# Blank google map when using it inside multiple fragments on a viewpager

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager where each "page" is a fragment. Each of the "page fragments" have a map fragment (google maps sdk for android) inside, added programatically using `getSupportFragmentManager` (If I use `getFragmentManager` it doesn't work either). Each added map is a new instance of `SupportMapFragment` (`MapFragment` doesn't work either).

On the first fragment, the one that is first added to the viewpager, the map works. At the other fragments, the non-interactive map just show itself as a grey square.

I'm using the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0' dependency.

All the added maps are using the `lite` version. I'm doing this with:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
options.liteMode(true);
options.mapToolbarEnabled(false);
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
```

I've read on some blogspots and here on Stackoverflow that **maybe** an app can only have one instance of google maps per process. Have anybody faced the same problem? Is my guess correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put a fragment into an other fragment, use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

[getChildFragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager())

> Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments
>   inside of this Fragment.

Comment: Great! It ended up not being a google maps specific bug, but a programming error of mine :) The awkward part is that some other fragments worked ok when not using the child fragment manager :/